# Strange Cascade View of Sales Product after using shorcode from WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, display

I have a problem with correctly displaing a sales product list in wordpress with woocommerce plugin.

When I want use a [sale_products per_page="12"] short code, my product are displayed in strange way. [image]

Can anyone know what can be wrong over here ?

Example page with this problem you can see here: http://www.modecode.pl/atlantic/about/

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the `pre` tag. If possible use a `div` or `section` instead, or you can try in css `pre { white-space: nowrap; }`